# IBM MQ v8 .NET authentication using Windows user rather than USER_ID_PROPERTY

Tags: .net, authentication, ibm-mq

No matter what I do when I try to connect (to write to) an IBM WebSphere MQ v8 it always errors out (`2035` unauthorized) as MQQueueManager connection looks to be using the user the service of the application is running on (Windows x64 server 2012) rather than the `MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY` that I have setup in the hash table.

The MQ is the same version as my libraries (v8) and has `ADOPTCTX(YES)` and we have performed `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)`.  Setting up my hashtable as follows for properties:

```
MQ_PROPERTIES = New Hashtable()
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, MQ_HOSTNAME)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, MQ_PORT)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, MQ_CHANNEL_NAME)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, MQ_USERNAME)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, MQ_PASSWORD)
MQ_PROPERTIES.Add(MQC.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, True)
```

With starting it as:

```
Using queueManager As New MQQueueManager(MQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, MQ_PROPERTIES)
```

Edit/Update:

{windows app user} = the account that the service of the app is running as.

dlls all v 8.0.0.4

Error in mq log (don't have direct access but as supplied):

```
  AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for '{windows app user}'.           

EXPLANATION:                                                                    

  Cause . . . . . :   The call to initialize the User ID '{windows app user}' failed     
with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.                                                
  Recovery  . . . :   Correct the error and try again.                          

----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2356 ------------------------------------------------------- 
 ************End of Data********************
```

---

CONNAUTH was set to SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWLDAP.  Settings for both IDPWLDAP and IDPWOS were as follows:

```
      5 : dis AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWLDAP)       
 AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.          
    AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWLDAP)                 
    AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP)                      ADOPTCTX(YES)      
    DESCR( )                                CONNAME( )         
    CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)                      CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) 
    CLASSUSR( )                             FAILDLAY(1)        
    BASEDNU( )                              LDAPUSER( )        
    LDAPPWD( )                              SHORTUSR( )        
    USRFIELD( )                             SECCOMM(NO)        
    ALTDATE(2017-10-20)                     ALTTIME(16.38.55)  

       2 : dis AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)        
  AMQ8566: Display authentication information details.         
     AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)                  
     AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)                        ADOPTCTX(YES)     
     DESCR( )                                CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)
    CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL)                      FAILDLAY(1)       
     ALTDATE(2017-10-23)                     ALTTIME(13.50.20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AUTHINFO` object that you are referencing has `AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP)`, but you do not have any of the required fields like `CONNAME`, `BASEDNU`, etc. Double check the queue manager's `CONNAUTH` setting to make sure you are viewing the right `AUTHINFO` object, you can do this with the command `DIS QMGR CONNAUTH`. 
 Whatever value is displayed in the queue manager's `CONNAUTH` field is the name of the `AUTHINFO` object you should be viewing.

If you want to use `AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP)` you need to configure it to point to a LDAP server with the required values. If you want it to use Windows OS authentication, then you would use `AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS)`.

Per an update from the OP (Hub3rt), the queue manager's `CONNAUTH` setting was incorrectly pointing to `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWLDAP` and after updating the queue manager's `CONNAUTH` setting to point to `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS` with `ADOPTCTX(YES)` authentication was successful.